# Php output in div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my script :

```
<script>
    $('form.subscribe').on('submit', function() {
        var that = $(this);
        url = that.attr('action');
        method = that.attr('method');
        data ={};
        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
              var that = $(this),
              name = that.attr('name'),
              value = that.val();
              data[name] = value;
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type:method,
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

        return false;
     });
</script>
```

I have an ajax function that gives me either an error message or a success message depending on what your input was on the form.

The messages that I get come from this php script:

```
<?php
    header("Refresh:7; url=contact.php");
    $email = $_POST['subscribefield'];

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "Dit emailadres klopt niet";
        die();
    }

    $to = "flash1996mph@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "Abonee voor de nieuwsbrief";
    $body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";

    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    echo "U heeft zich zojuist aangemeld voor de vandenberg nieuwsbrief";
?>
```

Right now im displaying the outputs with a `console.log()`. But I would like to display those in a `<div>` instead.

Comment: instead of the console.log have `$('#divid').html(response)` in success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to use jQuery [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set the response content in a DIV.

Replace following line

```
console.log(response);
```

with

```
$('#idOfDiv').html(response);
//or
$('.classOfDiv').html(response);
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a div element in your html page in which you want to show your message and give it a id like

`<div id="myMessage"></div>`

and replace your console.log line with

`$('#myMessage').text(response);`

and your message will start coming in div.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(selector).html()` to output HTML or `$(selector).text()` to output as plain text:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type:method,
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        $('div').html(respons);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create your div only in some specific case, then you can create div and then append data in AJAX success call.

In place of `console.log(response);`

Use :

```
$('#elementId').append("<div class=''>response</div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `console.log()` with `$('#div-id').html(response);`